# Extendscript - Change font size for TextLayer

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

How can I simply change the font size of a `TextLayer`? I tried like everything and the newest method I could find is to use `value.fontSize`:

```
var comp = app.project.activeItem,
    text = comp.layers.addText();
text.property("Source Text").value.fontSize = 10; // <-- Nope ._.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var
textProp = text.property("ADBE Text Properties").property("ADBE Text Document"),
textDoc = textProp.value;

textDoc.fontSize = 10;
textProp.setValue(textDoc);
```